# What is the contextual meaning of the word 'Offers' in the following sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

> You are new to the area. If you go alone, the land agent tries to take
>   advantage of you and offers you an expensive price?

Does '**offers**' stand for '**demands**' in this case?

Comment: Is there a reason why you think the standard definition of "offer" doesn't fit here?  ("Offer," as a verb, has a meaning entirely distinct from "demand.")  https://www.google.com/#q=offer%20definition

Comment: When we say to offer something,  its  usually  providing something and do the needful. however in this case,  it's a kind of deception by salesperson.

Comment: Offers aren't always about providing things that someone actually wants. The mugger can _offer_ you a choice of giving him your wallet or getting a knife in the gut.  Not a particularly pleasant choice, but still we would use the word "offer."  This is totally standard usage, at least in America, and compatible with standard definitions of offer (e.g. _present or proffer (something) for (someone) to accept or reject as so desired_.)  So much so that we have a term for offers that are extremely unpalatable:  _an offer [someone] can't refuse_  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeldwfOwuL8

Comment: _Salesperson tries to take advantage of you and offers you an expensive price_ - Where did you find this sentence? Did you make it up? It's a bit of an awkward use of "offer" (how awkward might depend on the industry; prices aren't negotiated the same way when dealing with, say, real estate, automobiles, and antiques). In any case, salespeople don't generally "offer an expensive price," but they might "make an outrageous offer" that the buyer finds too expensive.

Comment: @J.R:  The sentence was copy pasted from e-learning website.  Anyhow  Tofystedeth's  answer (the first answer which is the only answer as of now) does the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

Used like this, offers is more synonymous with "presents", or "suggests" than "demands."
A demand is usually forceful, but in this case, even though the salesperson is being deceitful, they are taking part in a negotiation.  It's just that their initial negotiating position is terrible.

Comment: The word "suggests"  fits   exactly  with the context.